# absolute path in 000webhost using spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

My problem is the absolute path and path in general. I wrote that this is 000webhost because it might be a host-specific problem, so here it is.

Like any host, this host has a `public_html` folder in the root. I've put images, CSS, JS files in that folder. Also, there's an `index.php` and an `install.php`. The rest of the app is above the `public_html` `(../public_html)` in a directory called `app`. I made a `constant.php` in the root where I made an `ABSOLUTE_PATH` constant that has a value of `dirname(__FILE__) . '/app/'`. `spl_autoload_register()` uses that constant to load classes and it doesn't work.

Now, you may think that I've done something wrong but, before the `spl_autoload` is even called, I have to load the class `Autoload.php` that is in the `app/libs/` directory. Also, I load `User.php` that is also in the `app/libs` directory and they both work fine.

So, my question is, why is the `ABSOLUTE_PATH` working with the `Autoload.php` and `User.php` but not inside the `spl_autoload_register`. Here is the directory tree...

```
root
    --- app
        --- libs
            - Autoload.php
            - User.php
    --- public_html
        -index.php
        -install.php
    - constants.php
```

And that is it. To repeat. In install.php, loading Autoload.php with this path works

```
ABSOLUTE_PATH . libs/Autoload.php
ABSOLUTE_PATH . libs/User.php
```

but inside Autoload.php, something like this doesn't work

```
ABSOLUTE_PATH . libs/Bootstrap.php
```

I know this is yet another 'path' question and not many want to see it, but I've been trying to solve it for 3 days now and I can't move on with my application if I don't.

Thank you in advance for all the answers

EDIT: I thought that I wouldn't have to post the `Autoload` class but here it is...

```
class Autoload
{

    public function classAutoloader($class) {
        $container = '';
        $delim = explode('_', $class);

        $file =  ABSOLUTE_PATH . implode('/', $delim) . '.php';

        if(!is_readable($file)) {
            return false;
        }

        include_once $file;
    }
}
```

This line of code

```
$delim = explode('_', $class);
```

is because the full name of the class is `Libs_Bootstrap` so splits the string to be 
`ABSOLUTE_PATH/libs/Bootstrap.php`. Note that the absolute path constant is made in the `constants.php` which is in the root.

Comment: Please post, your `spl_autoload_register()` implementation

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It was very basic which is very frustrating beacuse i lost days beacuse of it. The problem was in file names. I'm developing on windows which is case insensitive but was putting my files on linux who is case sensitive. Therefore, Libs_Bootstrap was in a file called bootstrap.php but the file Bootstrap.php was called. It's very basic. Lesson of the day: Always use case sensitive files.

Lesson of life in general: Learn Linux